# Automated multiplexer in vhdl

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, state-machines

I'd like to make a MUXer who switches between 2 signals let's say A and B. Signal A and B also generate both interrupts. The MUXer counts the interrupts and for example after n-interrupts of A, the output will become this of B.
If B generates m-interrupts, the output toggles back to A.

In underlying code I wait for 3 pulses of the A interrupt, during this the mux output is A. After that I wait for 5 pulses of the B interrupt while the mux out becomes B. The whole cycle is then repeated.

I'm implementing this with a 3 process FSM as explained here: http://www.csit-sun.pub.ro/courses/Masterat/Xilinx%20Synthesis%20Technology/toolbox.xilinx.com/docsan/xilinx4/data/docs/xst/hdlcode15.html

Can someone explain why it doesn't work properly? The vhdl code:

```
entity FSM_MUX is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in STD_LOGIC;
           A: in STD_LOGIC;
           A_INT : in STD_LOGIC;
           B: in STD_LOGIC;
           B_INT : in STD_LOGIC;
           START : in STD_LOGIC;
           MUX_OUT : out STD_LOGIC);
end FSM_MUX;

architecture Behavioral of FSM_MUX is

type state is (iddle,state_A,state_B) ;
signal old_state : state ;
signal new_state : state ;

begin
process(CLK)
    begin   
        if (CLK' event and CLK = '1') then
            if RST = '0' or START = '0' then
                old_state <= iddle ;
            else
                old_state <= new_state;
            end if;
        end if;
end process;


process (old_state,A_INT,B_INT)
    variable counter : integer range 0 to ((2**16)-1):=0;
    begin
        case old_state is
            when iddle          =>          if  A_INT = '1' then
                                                new_state <= state_A;
                                            else
                                                new_state <= iddle;
                                            end if;

            when state_A       =>          if A_INT = '1' then
                                                if counter < 3  then 
                                                    counter := counter + 1;
                                                    new_state <= state_A;
                                                else
                                                    counter := 0;
                                                    new_state <= state_B;
                                                end if;
                                            end if;

            when state_B       =>          if  B_INT = '1' then
                                                if counter < 5  then 
                                                    counter := counter + 1;
                                                    new_state <= state_B;
                                                else
                                                    counter := 0;
                                                    new_state <= state_A;
                                                end if;
                                            end if;

        end case;
end process;

process(old_state)     
begin
    case old_state is
        when iddle    =>        MUX <='0';
        when state_A =>         MUX <= A;
        when state_B =>         MUX <= B;       
   end case;

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's most likely subject to some of the usual defects of a 2-process SM. Check it for sensitivity list errors, latches or counters in the async process, etc. Or simply rewrite it in the simpler, smaller, more reliable single process form.

Comment: I actually answered it because the code "error" was obvious to me. But, next time please give a testbench which shows the faulty behaviour. And then describe in the question the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `counter` is actually a register, so you must describe it in the first process which is clocked. You cannot describe it in the second process, because you have less control on how often this process is resumed during the **same** clock cycle. The process is resumed whenever one of the signals in the process sensitivity list changes. I also prefer signals instead of variables because in most simulators you can add only signals to the waveform for debugging.

To control a `counter` register in the first (clocked) process from the second process, you need two control signals: `counter_rst` when the counter should be reseted, and `counter_inc` when the counter should be incremented.
The counter in the first process can then be described with:

```
    if (CLK' event and CLK = '1') then
        if counter_rst = '1' then   -- you may add RST and/or START here
            counter <= 0;
        elsif counter_inc = '1' then
            counter <= counter + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
```

You may add `RST`or `START` on the first condition to fit your needs.

For example, the counter is now incremented when you assign `counter_inc <= '1';` in the second process. This replaces the assignment of `counter := counter + 1;` in your current code. If no increment is needed, then you must assign `counter_inc <= '0'`. This is accomplished by making a default assignment at the start of the process. The control signal `counter_rst` is handled in a similar way. The `counter` must be added to the sensitivity list of the second process, because you want combinational logic here.

You also have to fix the counter checks. If you want to count 3 pulses, then you must count from 0 to 2.

Your code also needs a default assignment for `new_state`, because you didn't assigned a new value in each branch in the second process. In the last process it must read `MUX_OUT` instead of `MUX`, also `A` and `B` must be added to the process sensitivity list. Otherwise you get a latch.

This is the whole fixed code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FSM_MUX is
    Port ( CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in STD_LOGIC;
           A: in STD_LOGIC;
           A_INT : in STD_LOGIC;
           B: in STD_LOGIC;
           B_INT : in STD_LOGIC;
           START : in STD_LOGIC;
           MUX_OUT : out STD_LOGIC);
end FSM_MUX;

architecture Behavioral of FSM_MUX is

    type state is (iddle,state_A,state_B) ;
    signal old_state : state ;
    signal new_state : state ;
    signal counter : integer range 0 to ((2**16)-1) := 0;
    signal counter_inc : std_logic;         -- increment counter
    signal counter_rst : std_logic;         -- reset counter

begin
    process(CLK)
    begin   
        if (CLK' event and CLK = '1') then
            if RST = '0' or START = '0' then
                old_state <= iddle;
            else
                old_state <= new_state;
            end if;

            -- counter register
            if counter_rst = '1' then   -- you may add RST and/or START here
                counter <= 0;
            elsif counter_inc = '1' then
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (old_state, A_INT, B_INT, counter)  -- added counter
    begin
        counter_inc <= '0';             -- default assignment ...
        counter_rst <= '0';             -- ... may be overwritten below
        new_state   <= old_state;

        case old_state is
            when iddle =>
                if A_INT = '1' then
                    new_state <= state_A;
                else
                    new_state <= iddle;
                end if;

            when state_A =>
                if A_INT = '1' then
                    if counter < 2 then      -- count from 0 to 2 for 3 pulses
                        counter_inc <= '1';  -- increment counter
                        new_state <= state_A;
                    else
                        counter_rst <= '1';  -- reset counter
                        new_state <= state_B;
                    end if;
                end if;

            when state_B =>
                if B_INT = '1' then
                    if counter < 4 then      -- count from 0 to 4 for 5 pulses
                        counter_inc <= '1';  -- increment counter
                        new_state <= state_B;
                    else
                        counter_rst <= '1';  -- reset counter
                        new_state <= state_A;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end case;
    end process;

    process(old_state, A, B)            -- added A and B 
    begin
        case old_state is
            when iddle   => MUX_OUT <= '0';  -- MUX_OUT instead of MUX !
            when state_A => MUX_OUT <= A;
            when state_B => MUX_OUT <= B;
        end case;

    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

This was my testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FSM_MUX_tb is
end FSM_MUX_tb;

architecture sim of FSM_MUX_tb is

    signal CLK     : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    signal RST     : STD_LOGIC;
    signal A       : STD_LOGIC;
    signal A_INT   : STD_LOGIC;
    signal B       : STD_LOGIC;
    signal B_INT   : STD_LOGIC;
    signal START   : STD_LOGIC;
    signal MUX_OUT : STD_LOGIC;

begin  -- sim

    DUT: entity work.FSM_MUX
        port map (
            CLK     => CLK,
            RST     => RST,
            A       => A,
            A_INT   => A_INT,
            B       => B,
            B_INT   => B_INT,
            START   => START,
            MUX_OUT => MUX_OUT);

  -- clock generation
  CLK <= not CLK after 10 ns;

  -- waveform generation
  WaveGen_Proc: process
  begin
      RST <= '1';                       -- low-active, optional
      START <= '1';

      A <= '0';
      B <= '1';
      A_INT <= '0';
      B_INT <= '0';

      -- leave IDDLE state
      wait until rising_edge(CLK);
      A_INT <= '1';
      wait until rising_edge(CLK);
      A_INT <= '0';

      -- just some waiting
      wait until rising_edge(CLK);
      wait until rising_edge(CLK);

      -- 3 A_INT pulses to leave STATE_A
      for i in 1 to 3 loop
          wait until rising_edge(CLK);
          A_INT <= '1';
          wait until rising_edge(CLK);
          A_INT <= '0';
      end loop;  -- i

      -- 5 B_INT pulses to leave STATE_B
      for i in 1 to 5 loop
          wait until rising_edge(CLK);
          B_INT <= '1';
          wait until rising_edge(CLK);
          B_INT <= '0';
      end loop;  -- i

      wait;
  end process WaveGen_Proc;
end sim;
```

And this is the simulation output:

[image: simulation output]

Comment: Many thanks for the help! Not only for your efforts to provide the correct solution but also to explain neatly the why and how. I've tried everything with the sensivity list, though I forgot the default assignement of new_state. The fact that the counter was a register and such, I didn't know.

I'll try to find some direct "translations" of vhdl into hardware on the www, it seems my knowledge needs some polishing.

Thanks again!